# Ansible connection problem - /etc/hosts

Tags: ssh, ansible

ansible 2.9.6,
python 2.7.5

```
/etc/hosts -> server1 = 10.2.242.4
```

when I do `ansible server1 -m command -a "pwd" -vvv` ansible works properly, 
when I try run a playbook `ansible-playbook -i inventory test.yml -vvv` i still get:

```
<10.2.242.4> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<10.2.242.4> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=no -o ControlPersist=60s -o Port=22 -o 'IdentityFile="/root/.ssh/id_rsa"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="root"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/f076bfb64e 10.2.242.4 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~root && sleep 0'"'"''
<10.2.242.4> (0, '/root\n', '')
```

Inventory file:

```
[waw2]
server1 ansible_host=10.2.242.4

[waw2:vars]
ansible_ssh_port=22
ansible_user=root
```

My public key for root is added to the target server. In `ansible.cfg` in [ssh_connection] part nothing changed

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm assuming that you want to see the output when running the playbook. You'll have to print it out explicitly. See https://serverfault.com/q/537060 .

Comment: No, ansible can't connect to remote host when I run a playbook. In debug mode, is still 
`<10.2.242.4> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: root`

Comment: You might needs to add your ppk location in `ansible.cfg` as below `private_key_file = /root/.ssh/id_rsa`

Answer (score 0):

Solved, setting up `gather_subset=!hardware` in ansible.cfg helped